# Why blank white screen display for a second when going from one screen to another?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can you please tell tell why white screen display for a second (it take much time in android)when going from one screen to another .Then get back to same screen.
is there any way to stop this ?

Comment: You are going to need to be a bit more specific about your problem to get a good answer. Are the screens separate pages or are these divs you are displaying with jQuery? What is your program doing to change screens?

Comment: Actually I am navigate from one page to another it don't show white screen for second.But when I get back to starting screen i saw white blank screen for while .
I used both case $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"));

Comment: Is there a script on the first page that runs before the document ready event? It sounds like the first page takes longer to load and render. This is typically either because of a script, because the resources on the page are not cached, or because the data on the page must be generated server-side and the server response takes longer. Are any of these circumstances true?

Comment: I am getting data from data base..

Comment: is this possible to add new check box every new line .Mean append some default data using setInterval(which append data regularly).But every new line it create a check box.